# c and bit shifting in a char

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am new to C and having a hard time understanding why the code below prints out `ffffffff` when binary `1111111` should equal hex `ff`.

```
int i;
char num[8] = "11111111";
unsigned char result = 0;

for ( i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
    result |= (num[i] == '1') << (7 - i);
}
printf("%X", bytedata);
```

Comment: A `char` as binary 1111111 may have a value of -1.  An `int` with the value of -1 usually prints in hex as `ffffffff`.  The _value_ did not change.

Comment: @woodstok , Your edit makes my answer pointless.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not see your answer . Can i revert the edit?

Comment: Default argument promotions and sign extension. Duplicate hundreds of times over.

Answer (score 4):

You print `bytedata` which may be uninitialized.

Replace

```
printf("%X", bytedata);
```

with

```
 printf("%X", result);
```

Your code then run's fine. [code](http://ideone.com/YAObFf)

Although it is legal in C, for good practice you should  make

```
char num[8] = "11111111";
```

to

```
char num[9] = "11111111";
```

because in C  the null character ('\0') always appended to the string literal. And also it would not compile as a C++ file with g++.

**EDIT**

To answer your question

> If I use char the result is FFFFFFFF but if I use unsigned char the result is FF.

Answer:

*Case 1:*
In C size of char is 1byte(Most implementation). If it is unsigned we can
use 8bit and  hold maximum `11111111` in binary and `FF` in hex(decimal 255). When you print it with `printf("%X", result);`, this value implicitly converted to unsigned int  which becomes `FF` in hex.

*Case 2:*  But when you use char(signed), then MSB bit use as sign bit, so you can use at most  7 bit for your number whose range -128 to 127 in decimal. When you assign it with `FF`(255 in decimal) then [Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) occur which leads to [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).